# How to print all inputs into one array and format into currency]

Tags: python

I wrote the following code:

```
total_sum = 0
counter = 1

for n in range(6):
    numbers = float(input('Enter Bill #' + str(counter) + ': '))
    total_sum += float(numbers)
    counter += 1
```

Assuming I inputted six floats [1,2,3,4,5, 6], how can I print the six inputs such that it will print the following:

[$1, $2, $3, $4, $5, $6]?

Thank you for your help! :)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

After each input, you are adding the values to the sum variable. At the end of the loop you only have the total of the values you entered. To retain these values, you must store them in a collection like a list as you input them. After each input, you add it to the list using `list.append()`:

```
total_sum = 0
counter = 1
bills = []

for n in range(6):
    number = float(input(f'Enter Bill #{counter}: '))
    total_sum += float(numbers)
    bills.append(number)
    counter += 1
```

To print the values as currencies you can use the *locale* module and then initializing your preferred locale:

```
import locale
locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL, 'en_US.utf-8')
```

You can then use `locale.currency()` for the formatting:

```
formatted = list(map(locale.currency, bills))
print(formatted)
```

This is the same as:

```
formatted = []
for bill in bills:
   formatted.append(locale.currency(bill))

print(formatted)
```